# marker.setVisible(false) and marker.setMap(null) not working on all markes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, marker

I'am trying to change the markers while changing the zooming level in Google maps.
When the page is loaded there will be 6 markers(for regions) created on Google maps and pushed into an array, if the user zoomed in, the 6 markers will be deleted and replace with another markers(for cities) the number of markers varies, it's not fixed. when the user zoomed out the new markers are deleted and the old 6 markers are created again.
all of that is working for me except when the user zoom out only 6 markers(for cities) are deleted.
Here is sample of my code:`

```
      var markers=[];
    addRegionsMarkers();

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        if (map.getZoom() == 11)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
           { 
                markers[i].setVisible(false);
            }
            markers=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < cityListMap.length; i++) {

                (function ()
                {                        
                    var k = i;
                    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityListMap[i].latitude, cityListMap[i].longitude),
                        map: map,
                        labelContent: cityListMap[i].average.toFixed(1) + suffix,
                        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 20),
                        labelClass: "labels",// the CSS class for the label

                    });
                    marker.setIcon('.');
                    marker.setTitle(cityListMap[i].city);
                    markers.push(marker);

                }())
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (map.getZoom() == 8) {
                for (var j = 0; j < cityListMap.length ; j++)
                {
                    markers[j].setVisible(false);
                   // alert(markers[j].getTitle() + " id " + j);
                }
                markers =[];
                addRegionsMarkers();
            }
        }
    });

    function addRegionsMarkers()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            (function () {

                var k = i;
                var  marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position: locationsLatlng[i],
                    map: map,
                    labelContent: averagesArray[i] + suffix,
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 20),
                    labelClass: "labels",// the CSS class for the label

                });
                marker.setIcon('.');
                marker.setTitle(region[i]);
                markers.push(marker);
            }())
        }
    }`
```

I tried setVisible() and setMap(null) I'am having the same result only 6 markers are deleted, I checked if the for loop is working correctly by adding an alert in it and it does. I tried every thing i can think of until i got no idea, hope someone can explain to me why is that happening.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solve it :D....
I added a condition to my  if statements :
`if (map.getZoom() == 11 && markers.length==6)
{
.......
} 
.....
if (map.getZoom() == 8 && markers.length==cityListMap.length) {....}`

And now it works great